# Passing a parameter to a function inside a named export object literal

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

When using a named export to return an object literal composed of functions, is it possible to pass a parameter to one of those functions?

For example, let's say the function below returns conditional results depending on if user's an admin:

```
// gridConfig.js
function getColumnDefs(isAdmin = false) {
  // conditionally return columns
  return {
    orders: [ ... ], 
    ...
  }
}

export const config = {
  columnDefs: getColumnDefs(),
  rowDefs: getRowDefs(),
  ...
};

// main.js
import { config } from './gridConfig';

function doStuff() {
  const { columnDefs, rowDefs } = config;
  grid.columnDefs = columnDefs['orders'];
  ...
}
```

If I add the parameter to the function call inside the export, it says the param isn't defined. Adding a parameter to the export alias gives syntax errors. Even if it allowed this, I'm not clear where I'd pass my param inside main.js.

Is there some way of passing a parameter when structuring an export in this manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
export const config = admin => ({
  columnDefs: getColumnDefs(admin),
  rowDefs: getRowDefs(),
});

// main.js
import { config } from './gridConfig';

function doStuff() {
  const { columnDefs, rowDefs } = config(admin);//get the admin variable set before this line
  grid.columnDefs = columnDefs['orders'];
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe keeping it simple can be useful :)

```js
export const config = (isAdmin) => ({
  columnDefs: getColumnDefs(isAdmin),
  rowDefs: getRowDefs(),
  ...
});



// Import

import { config } from '[...]'; // Placeholder path of import


const myConfigFalse = config(false);
const myConfigTrue = config(true);
```